# Average time in GC

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

It is easy to display the current % in GC in a .NET app, but how can you show the average time in GC or event total time in GC so you can go through a complete scenario and measure if you really improved things??

% time in GC is defined as:

"% Time in GC
Displays the percentage of elapsed time that was spent performing a garbage collection since the last garbage collection cycle. This counter usually indicates the work done by the garbage collector to collect and compact memory on behalf of the application. This counter is updated only at the end of every garbage collection. This counter is not an average; its value reflects the last observed value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in measuring the elapsed time spent in GC, that data is available via ETW. PerfMonitor will collect and display that data for you - check out this MSDN Magazine article for an introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490356.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

GC is non-deterministic. As such it is difficult to optimise since you will get different results depending on how long your application has been running and what is the size in each generation.

An easier approach - and to be honest much more reliable - is to calculate number of objects you are creating in a particular method. Best practices such as not creating an object in a loop, etc will help.

Comment: Agreed the only sensible option is to give it less "garbage" to collect.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Visual Studio has a profiler built-in.  There are also third-party profilers, free and ones that cost money.  Profiler can show you what percentage of time you're spending in GC.

**EDIT** There are some common misconceptions about CPU time spent in any old thread, including GC thread.  For example, it's possible to lock against a synchronization object that GC thread uses.  In this case, GC will be on stand-by, but will not incur a measurable amount of CPU time.  These scenarios are hard to inspect without proper tooling.

Comment: Actually I need the total time. Process Explorer shows you %time in GC, not total time :(

Comment: @pablo Please have a look my edits.  You might notice that VS Profiler is much more pleasant to work with than the windows APIs directly.